Usage and reason for が in XというのがYだ sentence
These are two replies from a long Twitter debate over broadly whether Japan should increase military spending for threats of foreign invasion (much more but not important here, DeepL translation):

[A]脱アメリカは勿論するべきだと思いますが、独立した国家として備える為にも今軍事力をアメリカに頼ってる分日本が拡大すべきでは？勿論軍用機等もいずれは全て国内生産にすべきだと思いますが、
又脅威は中国だけじゃないと思うのですが、、
[B]日本が「アメリカに頼っている」というのが、アメリカが日本人に植え付けた幻想です。
アメリカが日本に負担を押し付けて、日本の国土を基地にしているだけです。
[A]Of course, I think we should get rid of the U.S., but in order to
prepare ourselves as an independent nation, shouldn't Japan expand its
military power to the extent that it now relies on the U.S.? Of
course, I think that all military aircraft should eventually be
produced domestically. I also think that China is not the only threat.
[B]The illusion that Japan is "dependent on the US" is an illusion
that the US has instilled in the Japanese people. The U.S. is simply
using Japanese land as a base, placing the burden on Japan.

I am curious as to why が is used here instead of the more standard というのは to define/interpret "Japan is relying on America". I have a feeling this falls into the exhaustive listing property, because the usage does somewhat feel as if it is somehow singling out/emphasizing what is coming before it.
Questions:
1.)Why が is natural here (does how B is responding to A with a bit of emotion for emphasis have something to do with this usage?)
2.)Is using は with this context still natural and how does it change the sentence?

Related が vs. は in のが/のは...である cleft-sentence structure

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/101477/5010

This が is an exhaustive-listing-が, which you are probably familiar with in simple cases like "彼が日本語を話せます".
Instead of just using は, this が adds an nuance of "exactly", "precisely", "nothing but", or "THAT is the point".

日本が「アメリカに頼っている」というのが、アメリカが日本人に植え付けた幻想です。

That precise idea that Japan relies on America is the fantasy that the Americans planted in the Japanese.
"Japan depends on America" — THAT is the fantasy the Americans have installed in the Japanese.


